# 'uninitialized constant SubcategoriesController' - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a SubcategoriesController

```
class Categories::SubcategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @subcategory = Subcategory.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

These are my routes

```
resources :categories do 
    resources :subcategories, except: [:index, :show]
  end
```

When I'm trying to visit `categories_path`, it throws `uninitialized constant SubcategoriesController`

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current route configuration expects to find `SubcategoriesController` in `app/controllers/subcategories_controller.rb`, but you have declared `Categories::SubcategoriesController` (perhaps in `app/controllers/categories/subcategories_controller.rb`).

Try moving and renaming the controller so router can find it.

Hope that helps!